# How to 'conda activate my_env' with no admin

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I have Anaconda installed as Administrator on my work pc. It was installed by my administrator via a very policy heavy process (I work for a large company and I have to request software).

So I have 2 problems that I encounter when trying to use it.

1 - I CAN'T "conda install package" into the root env as I don't have admin access. I CAN "conda install package" into my_env because my_env directory is under C:\User...

BUT...

2 - I have no access to the command prompt (has been disabled by admin company wide). So I cant activate my_env. I have "re-created" my own version of cmd prompt using a batch file but that doesn't work when I try and "conda activate my_env".

I don't want to have to ring up my company IT helpdesk every time I want to activate an environment.

So, any ideas of how I can get around these problems?